# SSIS - ADO Destinations error ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: windows, ssis

I'm very familiar with SSIS but have a situation where I can't get my head around and couldn't find any solutions on the internet. No idea anymore where to look for...

Situation:

Had a perfectly working project on Windows 2012 with Target SQL Server 2017. We migrated to Windows 2022 and SQL Server 2022.

The same project fails on a very simple data transformation. It says ADO NET Destination Error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

The strange thing is that as long as I don't change the TargetServerVersion in the properties to SQL 2019 or SQL 2022 (so I stay on 2017), there is no issue. When I change to 2019 or 2022, the ADO NET Destination gets buggy.

We are on the latest Microsoft Drivers but reverted already back to the previous one (no success).

The source is an IBM ODBC connection. The query itself runs fine and produces the desired output.

[image]

When we preview the result in the Source connection, we get the normal output. The issue is with the decimal fields.

[image]

At run-time (enabled a data viewer on the stream), we see that the decimal numbers get completely mixed up.

[image]

Which eventually end up in an outOfRange error. Which is perfectly correct if we look at the produced output.

[image]

I have no idea why the numbers change at runtime. As said before, when I change the TargetServerVersion back to 2017, this buggy behaviour doesn't appear.

Tried other destinations (like OLE DB), but same behaviour.
Reverted back to previous drivers but same behaviour

Comment: Excellent first question and I hate that I can't answer it. I would open a ticket with Microsoft support. It's not the ADO.NET Destination that is busted as I suspect a Derived Column in its place would show the same wrong values. There's something with the 2019 and 2022 pipelines that is messing this up. There's probably some regional/localization in play as well since your decimal separator is a `,` Out of curiosity, which IBM database are you connecting to? And are you using the 32 or 64 bit version of the driver?

Comment: Oh, here's an interesting experiment while you wait for support, if you modify your source query to cast the highlighted columns as strings, what does it look like when it gets to the pipeline? `SELECT *, CAST(OPERATIONALTIME AS varchar(100)) AS OPERATIONALTIME_DEBUG FROM mytable;`

Comment: It's just a DB2 (now idea what version) and we run a 32bit driver but we also run the 64bit on a different machine and same thing. Don't think it's related to the source. I did wrapped a cast to varchar around it and that resulted in a "normal" output. Have a screenshot but can't seem to upload it on a comment. But of course no option to start rewriting all the packages...

Comment: If Microsoft Support is an option for you/your client, I'd totally make that call. This seems a clear cut case of their code behaving differently (assuming of course you're patched up to date) and wrongly. I had an issue back in the 2005 days where under load the back half of columns were being truncated. They provided an updated DLL and eventually same change was patched back into the product.